# registering click event on dynamically added buttons jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

## I am using bootstrap

Following is my code to dynamically fetch feeds and then add them on the page by appending inside the division whose id is 'feeds':

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://api.feedzilla.com/v1/categories/'+newsId+'/articles.json',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',

    // to execute when successfully got json response
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response.articles, function(){
            var feed=   "<div class='media well'>"+
                            "<div class='media-body'>"+
                                "<h4 class='media-heading'>"+this.title+"</h4>"+
                                "<h6>"+this.publish_date+"</h6>"+
                                "<p>"+this.summary+"</p>"+
                                "<a href='"+this.url+"' target='_blank'>Continue Reading</a>"+
                            "</div><br><br>"+
                            "<button class='showinfo btn pull-right' id='info'>Show Info</button>"+
                        "</div>";

            $('#feeds').append(feed);
        });
    },

    // to execute when error
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("Server error!");
    },

    // execute at last whether success or error
    complete: function(){

    }
});
```

As you can see I am adding a class 'showinfo' as well as id 'info' to dynamically added buttons.

Now following is my event handler:

```
    // SHOW INFO BUTTON CLICK HANDLER
    $('.showinfo').click(function(){
      alert('triggered');
    });
```

But it does not work :(!! neither with id: $('#info').click()!! 
**If I don't add the button dynamically, it works perfect.** Why this is so?

Comment: duplicate of thousand other questions...

Comment: the id attribute should be unique

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [**`on()`**](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$('#feeds').on('click', '.showinfo', function() {
    alert('triggered');
});
```

The above binds any **click** event on any element matching **`.showinfo`** inside **`#feeds`** to the specified callback function.

Also, note that the elements that should match (`.showinfo` in this case) **need not** exist at the time of binding (hence it applies to dynamically added elements as well).

Comment: +1, but a bit of an explanation would feed him for a lifetime ;)

Comment: @Archer - Yes. Was in the process of adding that actually. Done.

Comment: @techfoobar Thanks!! please feed me for the lifetime, add some explanation :D

Comment: @stalin - Have added some. Hope it helps. Also lookup, http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: This video helped me https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unk-U_LQWuA

Answer (score 4):

You have to do [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamically added elements.

```
  // SHOW INFO BUTTON CLICK HANDLER
    $('#feeds').on("click",'.showinfo' ,function(){
      alert('triggered');
    });
```

And why on() works ??

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().

Answer (score 2):

`.click` works for existing objects. If your controls are going to be added dynamically, then use `.on`(or `live` - but i's deprecated). It attaches the events for the objects which are added dynamically.

```
$('.showinfo').on('click', function(){
  alert('triggered');
});
```